# What does "regards" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning, word-meaning

I emailed my teacher a question, and he answered with the following sentence:

> Titan atmospheric conditions are nearly identical to Earth's in many **regards**.

What does *regards* mean in this context?

Comment: in many regards = in many points, in many aspects, in many things.

Answer (score 2):

It means "in many ways." You may also see "in many respects" or "in many aspects" sometimes. They all mean mostly the same thing.

Comment: Hello phenry, so atmospheric pressure can be one of these "regards"?

Comment: @Carlo_R.: Yes, it can mean any aspect that is worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

It's a "comprehensible" usage, but very unusual. I suggest you forget about *regards*, and use *respects*...

> *in many **respects** it is similar* [(28,700 hits in Google Books)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22in%20many%20regards%20it%20is%20similar%22&oq=%22in%20many%20regards%20it%20is%20similar%22&gs_l=serp.3...1299628.1308031.3.1308661.29.29.0.0.0.0.112.1566.28j1.29.0....0...1c.1.19.psy-ab.w7vPCXXWLLQ&pbx=1&biw=1270&bih=930&cad=cbv&sei=S0zTUez1MoWY0AXbxIHIBQ#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22in%20many%20respects%20it%20is%20similar%22&oq=%22in%20many%20respects%20it%20is%20similar%22&gs_l=serp.3...2497.4661.0.5147.11.11.0.0.0.0.215.1092.7j3j1.11.0....0...1c.1.19.psy-ab.BsaL6-OQ-eE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.d2k&fp=c030e09ea1435dc8&biw=1270&bih=930)
>    *in many **regards** it is similar* [(10 hits)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22in%20many%20regards%20it%20is%20similar%22&oq=%22in%20many%20regards%20it%20is%20similar%22&gs_l=serp.3...1299628.1308031.3.1308661.29.29.0.0.0.0.112.1566.28j1.29.0....0...1c.1.19.psy-ab.w7vPCXXWLLQ&pbx=1&biw=1270&bih=930&cad=cbv&sei=S0zTUez1MoWY0AXbxIHIBQ)

Comment: And 252 hits for "in many aspects it is similar".

Comment: @Bob: Not to mention 18,900 hits for [in many **ways** it is similar](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22in+many+ways+it+is+similar%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I was only really interested in making the point that **regards** isn't at all common in OP's construction. Personally I wouldn't endorse it at all except in restricted contexts where you say things like *"in that regard"* meaning *"**looked at in that way**"*, which I don't think really applies here.